# How to cast enum to uint in structured text

Tags: casting, codesys, structured-text

I have a structured text program running in codesys 3.5, in which I want to set the mode of some motor to several values. In order to have good encapsulated code I defined the following struct:

```
{attribute 'strict'}
TYPE PD4_modes :
(
    no_mode := 0,
    position:= 1,
    velocity := 2,
    homing_mode := 3
) UINT;
END_TYPE
```

However as soon as I try to assign this value to the appropriate variable (an `sint`) which drives the motor mode as so:

```
mot1_ctrmode = PD4_modes.homing_mode
```

I get the error: `type PD4_modes cannot be cast to sint`. Why is that? I thought I defined the modes as uint in the struct? Therefore no casting should be necessary right? I also tried to erase the attribute `strict` but that did not help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `SINT` is not the same as `UINT`:

- **SINT**: **S**mall (signed) **INT**, 8 bits, (-128 to 127)
- **UINT**: **U**nsigned **INT**, 16 bits, (0 to 65535)

They are completely different integer types. If you want, you can cast one into another (as long as the number fits in the other type, otherwise you may loose some data). [Quirzo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69310970/11427841) Already showed that, but in short, you can use the `UINT_TO_SINT` function. Another option is to use a [UNION](https://help.codesys.com/webapp/_cds_datatype_union;product=codesys;version=3.5.17.0).

However, if you can, you should try changing the type of one or the other to match the same, or better yet, you could define `mot1_ctrmode` to be `PD4_modes` and let the compiler do that work for you. If the types of `mot1_ctrmode` and `PD4_modes` match, you will avoid casting from an ENUM to raw integer.

If you want to avoid casting from a raw integer to an ENUM, then you have to either remove the [strict attribute](https://help.codesys.com/api-content/2/codesys/3.5.17.0/en/_cds_datatype_enum/#id3) (doing `PD4_modes_enum_variable := mot1_ctrmode;` with `{attribute 'strict'}` will give `C0358:  'mot1_ctrmode' is not a valid value for strict ENUM type 'PD4_modes'` error), or use a UNION as I mentioned previousely.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the enumeration to SINT.
For example:

```
//Shorter way:
mot1_ctrmode  := TO_SINT(PD4_modes.homing_mode);

//Typical way
mot1_ctrmode  := UINT_TO_SINT(PD4_modes.homing_mode);
```

You could also consider defining the enumeration as SINT or the mot1_ctrmode as UINT, if possible. So no typecasting would be needed.

Comment: +1 for this answer, this would indeed solve the problem I feel badfor not figuring out this myself. I picked Guiorgys answer, because he detailed a bit more...